# Why this BigQuery transaction is not rollbacked?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to exploit sessions in BigQuery python API, in order to perform multi-statement transactions, like it is shown in [this blogpost](https://dev.to/stack-labs/bigquery-transactions-over-multiple-queries-with-sessions-2ll5).

This is my code for the context manager:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery


class BigquerySession:
    """ContextManager wrapping a bigquerySession."""

    def __init__(self, bqclient: bigquery.Client, bqlocation: str = "EU") -> None:
        """Construct instance."""
        self._bigquery_client = bqclient
        self._location = bqlocation
        self._session_id = None

    def __enter__(self) -> str:
        """Initiate a Bigquery session and return the session_id."""
        job = self._bigquery_client.query(
            "SELECT 1;",  # a query can't fail
            job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig(create_session=True),
            location=self._location,
        )
        self._session_id = job.session_info.session_id
        job.result()  # wait job completion
        return self._session_id

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        """Abort the opened session."""
        if exc_type:
            print("Transaction failed, performing rollback")
            job = self._bigquery_client.query(
                "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;",
                job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
                    create_session=False,
                    connection_properties=[
                        bigquery.query.ConnectionProperty(key="session_id", value=self._session_id)
                    ],
                ),
                location=self._location,
            )
            job.result()
        if self._session_id:
            # abort the session in any case to have a clean state at the end
            # (sometimes in case of script failure, the table is locked in
            # the session)
            job = self._bigquery_client.query(
                "CALL BQ.ABORT_SESSION();",
                job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
                    create_session=False,
                    connection_properties=[
                        bigquery.query.ConnectionProperty(
                            key="session_id", value=self._session_id
                        )
                    ],
                ),
                location=self._location,
            )
            job.result()

        return False
```

It appears to work fine, but if I try to interrupt the transaction without committing it on purpose it will write the results anyways without rollbacking, even if performing it explicitly.

This is an example of transaction:

```py
# Open transaction
job = self.client.query(
    "BEGIN TRANSACTION;",
    job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
        create_session=False,
        connection_properties=[
            bigquery.query.ConnectionProperty(key="session_id", value=session_id)
        ]
    ),
    location=self.dataset.location,
)
job.result()

# DML queries

job = self.client.query(
    aggregation_query,
    job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
        create_session=False,
        connection_properties=[
            bigquery.query.ConnectionProperty(key="session_id", value=session_id)
        ],
        destination=f"{self.dataset.project}.{self.dataset.dataset_id}.{table_name}",
        create_disposition="CREATE_NEVER",
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND"
    ),
    location=self.dataset.location,
)
print(job.result())

# This will avoid the commit statement
raise KeyboardInterrupt

# Commit transaction
job = self.client.query(
    "COMMIT TRANSACTION;",
    job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
        create_session=False,
        connection_properties=[
            bigquery.query.ConnectionProperty(key="session_id", value=session_id)
        ],
    ),
    location=self.dataset.location,
)
job.result()
```

As I said, after running this code, the rollback statement is run, I can also see it in the run jobs from the console, however I will still find the written rows in the destination table afterwards.

My hypothesis are 2: the select with destination statement is not considered DML and therefore is not affected by the rollback operation or there is a bug in the session API (however it should be supported following the [relative documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/transactions#statements_supported_in_transactions)), which is still marked as [preview](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.create_session) in the documentation.

However I can't prove which of these is correct.

Comment: In SQL the `SELECT` statement is not consider a DML statement, The statements considered for DML are: `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE` and `INSERT INTO SELECT`, so possible as it not considers the `SELECT` statement the Operation is not being Rolled back.

Comment: I understand, but in this case the documentation is misleading. It states that `SELECT` operations are supported in transactions, however they are only partially supported.  Am I right?

Comment: @Tonca It is a good practice here to [post your solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Thank you @HectorMartinezRodriguez. I am not satisfied with my solution, since I decided to not use this BigQuery feature in the end. I was still waiting for contributions, but at this point I guess there won't be any.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome this issue by using an `INSERT INTO` statement, instead of specifying the destination table using the python API. I am guessing that the transaction feature does not cover the python API methods. I am not sure if this is a bug, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this topic.

I finally decided to not use the transaction feature since it has proven to be quite unreliable and not yet ready for production.